# Add elements of a list to the last elements of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, where the number of elements of list 1 = number of sublists of list 2:

```
list1 = {a,b};
list2 = {{f,g,h,i},{j,k,l,m}}
```

I would like to add elements of list1 to the last elements of list2, so I did

```
list3 = MapThread[Append,{list2,list1}];

list3 = list3 /. {x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_,x5_} -> {x1,x2,x3,x4+x5}
```

It works but I suspect there is a more efficient way with, perhaps, `MapAt` or  some combination of functions that I can't figure out. How would you do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With padding:

```
list2 + Map[PadLeft[{#},4]&, list1]
```

> {{f, g, h, a + i}, {j, k, l, b + m}}

Answer (score 5):

See code below:

```
list2[[;; , -1]] = list2[[;; , -1]] + list1;
list2
```

> {{f, g, h, a + i}, {j, k, l, b + m}}

EDIT:
or the more compact, suggested by @Henrik Schumacher in the comment below:

```
list2[[;; , -1]] += list1
```

Comment: Or `list2[[;; , -1]] += list1`.

Comment: True, much nicer :)